# Twitter Not Saving Unique Tweet ID

Tags: php, twitter, pdo

I have built a php script that saves results from a hash tag search and when I save the tweet ID it just tries saving a duplicate. 
I have set a UNIQUE constraint on the table and it obviously doesn't save anything but the first tweet and it throws the error below. Which isn't surprising

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 2
```

If I remove the constraint it saves all the tweets correctly but the tweet ID is duplicated

I have tried displaying the tweet in the output from the same variable I'm using to put in the table and it is all UNIQUE and correct so the variable is correct. So I can only assume some weirdness is going on all by itself

```
foreach($results as $result) {
$tweet_ID = $result->id_str;
$userID = $result->from_user_id_str;
$tweetText = $result->text;
$tweet_time = strtotime($result->created_at);
$createdAt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ',$tweet_time);

echo '<div>'. $tweet_ID . 
     '<div class="tweet" >' . displayTweet($result->text),"\r\n" .
        '<div class="user">'. '<strong>Posted </strong>' . date('j/n/y H:i:s ',$tweet_time). '<strong> By </strong>' . 
        '<a rel="nofollow" href="http://twitter.com/' . $result->from_user. '">' . $result->from_user .
        '</div>' .
     '</div>';  

// Execute query 
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$hashtag."(tweetID, userID, tweetText, createdAt) VALUES(:tweetID, :userID, :tweetText, :createdAt)");
$stmt->execute(array(':tweetID' => $tweet_ID, ':userID' => $userID, ':tweetText' => $tweetText, ':createdAt' => $createdAt));
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I can't figure out for the life of me why it is saving some random numbers

The number that it is adding is 2147483647. Doesn't mean anything to me.
Any help on what is going on would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This number `2147483647`  clearly indicates that you are not using **64-bit** integers to store tweet id. Tweet ids are **64-bit** integers.  You should use `BIGINT` data type for `tweetID` column.

```
`tweetID` BIGINT UNSIGNED
```

The special value you are getting `2147483647` is because all the upper bits are truncated when a **64-bit** tweet id is cast to **32-bit** `signed int`. If you could have use `unsigned int` The number would have been higher. But not more than `2147483647*2`. Tweet ids are much higher than that. You have to use 64-bit `unsigned int`

Also I see you are using a dynamic table name for your insert query. Dont do that! One single table can hold a lot of rows before you experience performance problem.

Comment: For clarification, 2147483647 is the largest value a signed 32-bit integer can hold. 64-bit signed integers can hold up to 2147483648 ^ 2 - 1.

Comment: God I feel stupid it was something as simple as that. Thank you for your help. Changed to 64 bit works like a charm

Comment: I'm saving them dynamically because I need all the data separated into its own tables uniquely named. I know it's not ideal but I can't think of a better way to do it unless you have suggestions